# Command not going to label after loop?

Tags: windows, batch, label

I am trying to check Task Manager for a game process (mygame.exe) and if that process does not exist, loop back to the label "WAIT_EXE".

It sounds straightforward but it's not working, the volume doesn't get lowered on the game:

```
:WAIT_EXE
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mygame.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "mygame.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto WAIT_EXE
%~dp0nircmd.exe setappvolume mygame.exe 0.1
```

On its own that last command does lower the volume.

Could it be that tasklist does not throw any error when it doesn't find something so there's no errorlevel 1?

Cheers folks.

Comment: Try adding some debugging output: add `echo set volume` just after `:SET_VOLUME` and see if it is really running that part.

Comment: I have since taken that label out, it wasn't needed. Still no joy. I'll edit the question down to what I have now.

Comment: ok, well what happens if you add `echo set volume` to a line just after `%~dp0nircmd.exe setappvolume mygame.exe 0.1`? Do you see `set volume` in the console? If so, then you know that the set volume command was run.

Comment: Sorry man I have had such a nightmare doing this I just ended up fixing it with an AutoIt2 script that waits for the game window title. Then I used "start /wait" and it all worked.